# Set dual axes in Tensorboard for two different charts

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Here are the two examples:
**1 perfectly worked as the scales was same:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random

writer_1 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_1")
writer_2 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_2")

log_var = tf.Variable(0.0)
tf.summary.scalar("loss", log_var)

write_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(100):
    # for writer 1
    summary = session.run(write_op, {log_var: random.rand()})
    writer_1.add_summary(summary, i)
    writer_1.flush()

    # for writer 2
    summary = session.run(write_op, {log_var: random.rand()})
    writer_2.add_summary(summary, i)
    writer_2.flush()
    print(i)
```

Got this figure which was understandable : 
[image: good image]

But take a look at the second case where the values do not fit in the same range. In that case I need to have two different axes  on same chart, so that I get a good and understandable image. Check the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random

writer_1 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_1")
writer_2 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_2")

log_var = tf.Variable(0.0)
tf.summary.scalar("loss", log_var)

write_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(100):
    # for writer 1
    summary = session.run(write_op, {log_var: i*10})
    writer_1.add_summary(summary, i)
    writer_1.flush()

    # for writer 2
    summary = session.run(write_op, {log_var: random.rand()})
    writer_2.add_summary(summary, i)
    writer_2.flush()
    print(i)
```

See the image obtained:
[image: bad image]

Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two axes in the same plot, you would have to put the values in two different plots. It is a bit tricky, because the plots are determined by the name of the summary, so in your example you would need to build the summary objects by hand.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random

writer_1 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_1")
writer_2 = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/plot_2")

log_var = tf.Variable(0.0)

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(100):
    # for writer 1
    log1 = session.run(log_var, {log_var: i*10})
    summary1 = tf.train.Summary()
    summary1.value.add(tag='loss1', simple_value=log1)
    writer_1.add_summary(summary1, i)
    writer_1.flush()

    # for writer 2
    log2 = session.run(log_var, {log_var: random.rand()})
    summary2 = tf.train.Summary()
    summary2.value.add(tag='loss2', simple_value=log2)
    writer_2.add_summary(summary2, i)
    writer_2.flush()
    print(i)
```

Comment: I guess this is good one. But you know the values might be changing in the course of time. So this trick won't last long.